# Batch Zip files only if they don't exist not working for identical file names in different directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

I'm trying to set up a batch file (in Windows) that will zip files ONLY if they don't already exist as zips.

I've *almost* got it working, but it fails for identical file names that exist in *different* directories (it simply ignores them, assuming that it's done them already).

I figure that my code simply looks at file names, ignoring their location, and that somehow I need to also reference their location.

I've tried searching (and will continue to search) for a solution and will post back here if I find something, but hopefully someone can suggest something.

The below code, as I understand it, will recursively search for all fcs files and zip (7z) them if it can't also find the equivalent file in 7z format.

```
FOR /R %%f in (*.fcs) DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~nf.7z" (
            7z a -mm=LZMA2 -mx=1 -mmt24 "%%~pf%%~nf.7z" "%%f" 
    )
```

It almost works, but not when identical file names exist in different directories, when it will simply ignore them because it thinks they've already been zipped.

What do I need to add to get it to recognise identical names in different directories?

I've considered something like comparing two lists e.g.

```
dir /b /s /a-d *.fcs >FilestoZip
dir /b /s /a-d *.7z >FilesAlreadyZipped
```

but my knowledge of batch files is too limited!

Comment: `IF NOT EXIST "%%~nf.7z"` does not check an entire tree for any occurrence of `basename.7z`, it is checking only in the current working directory. If you decide to compare two lists, you could use `FINDSTR` to choose those in one list which do not exist in the other, and send those to 7z.exe. If you open a Command Prompt window and enter `findstr /?` you can read the usage information for that particular command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it!

The key was simple - changing the IF NOT EXIST to include the path! (i.e. just adding a p to "%%~nf.7z".

=)

Complete, working code:

```
FOR /R %%f in (*.fcs) DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~pnf.7z" (
            7z a -mm=LZMA2 -mx=1 -mmt24 "%%~pf%%~nf.7z" "%%f" 
    )
```

EDIT - for a *slight* speed up (~10%), you could also use the BROTLI codec from [here](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd/releases) and the following code:

```
FOR /R %%f in (*.imd) DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~pnf.7z" (
         7z a -mm=BROTLI -mx=2 -mmt24 "%%~pf%%~nf.7z" "%%f" 
   )
```

Comment: Why not adding the drive also, like `%%~dpnf.7z`? and why do you not write it exactly the same way in the second line (since `%%~[d]pf%%~nf.7z` is the same as `%%~[d]pnf.7z`)?

Comment: I don't need the drive, as I'm only working on one drive. As for the other suggestion - I don't know. I just copied the code I found elsewhere, and it works, so I'm not going to bother changing it!